# Giving an ActorPath for a testProbe

Tags: scala, testing, akka

I have some code that sends a message to an actor using it's ActorPath not ActorRef

```
system.actorSelection("/user/myActor") ! "a message"
```

I need to make sure that this message is really sent. So I need in my tests to create a testProbe (or something similar) that lives in this actor path, so that it receives those message.

```
val probe = TestProbe()
val system.actorOf(probe.ref, "myActor") // ??? I want to give my probe name and path
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hard coding actor paths is likely to make you unhappy later, wherefore you should take the difficulty of testing it as a design hint. I would recommend using ActorRef as a first choice, and only if that cannot be made to work fall back to ActorPath, but then keep it flexible by telling the actor which path to use (in a message or via the constructor).

Comment: I agree, though in my experience paths are helpful as a solution in case of cyclic dependencies between actors and another case is when you need to dynamically change implementation (just to kill the current actor and start a new one under the same path)

Answer (score 7):

I figured out a non elegant solution.
I defined a helper actor called "ForwardActor"

```
class ForwardActor(to: ActorRef) extends Actor {
    def receive = {
        case x => to.forward(x)
    }
}
```

then in my test case

```
 val probe = TestProbe() 
 system.actorOf(Props(new ForwardActor(probe.ref)), "myActor")
 probe.expectMsg(...)
```

Comment: I'll wait for other answers, to see if test-kit contains a solution for this usecase, without such tweak.

Comment: @Roland is correct most folks should be using an ActorRef there may be certain scenarios where you want an ActorSelection instead to do "fire and forget" if you handle reliability at the application level. in which case this solution making a forwarding actor from which you can get an ActorPath or ActorSelection works.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a small library/DSL for dealing with such cases (it also allows to create more complex hierarchies and listen for messages for certain elements of path) https://github.com/stanislav-chetvertkov/spy-tree. The above case can be dealt like the following:

```
import com.github.spytree.ActorListenersDSL._

val myActorProbe = TestProbe()
("myActor" replyTo myActorProbe.ref).materialize

context.actorSelection("/user/myActor") ! "a message"

val response = myActorProbe.expectResponse[String]
response.message shouldBe "a message"
```