# Unit Testing Components that Uses an Akka Actor

Tags: scala, unit-testing, akka, akka-testkit

First of all, I am not asking how to unit test an Akka Actor. I know the techniques to do that. My problem is slightly different.

I am developing a Scala program, let's call it the `client`, that does not use Akka Actors. However, the program uses a library, let's call it the `server`, whose interface is implemented using an Akka Actor.

Then, through the *ask pattern*, the `client` interacts with the `server`.

```
// This is the client program
class Client(uri: String) {
  implicit val context: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("client-actor-system")
  private val mainActor = context.actorSelection(uri)

  def connect: Future[SomeClass] = {
    implicit val timeout: Timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
    (mainActor ? Connect()).mapTo[CreationResponse]
  }
}
```

Now, I want to write down some unit tests for `Client` class. Unit testing means to test a class in isolation. Every external dependency should be mocked.

How can I mock the reference to `mainActor` inside `Client` class? How can I inject in the actor system a mock actor for `mainActor`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would inject the `mainActor` actor selection into the client, and create that using Akka TestKits.

Of course, you need an `ActorSelection`, not an `ActorRef`. Some solutions for that can be found here:

[Giving an ActorPath for a testProbe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285260/giving-an-actorpath-for-a-testprobe)

Or alternatively, you could make `mainActor` an `ActorRef` by sending an `Identify` message to the `ActorSelection`.

Comment: I suppose that your approach is the right and only one. The only thing I do not like it is that the use of Akka is not hidden into the `Client` class anymore.

Comment: an alternative is to create a factory method that builds your actor, and in the test you override it to return  `probe.ref`